# AV prevents me from changing settings on remote machine

Tags: windows, permissions, uac

I use a program called [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) which is essentially a virtual/network Keyboard/mouse. One computer acts as the server and the other client PCs can then use the keyboard and mouse. 
If you want to interact with UAC dialogues (win 7) you can run the Synergy processes as services and give them elevated permissions so you can interact with UAC dialogue boxes etc.

I have found however that if I try to access any of my anti-virus (Kaspersky internet security) interface features (anything in the GUI console at all) on a client machine, I am unable to click on anything inside that window.

What would be causing this kind of behaviour? I thought giving it service level 
permissions that it would be enough to interact with the AV console as well?

Why can I still use RDP to click on these windows as well?

Hope someone can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kasperksy does this to protect itself. The same is true if you try and change it via a remote desktop program like TeamViewer/LogMeIn etc. I had a nightware with it!

The only way around it is to use a normal keyboard and mouse, and then give full access/permission to the program in question.

Or, when RDP is needed, I had to talk the person on the other end how to give my RDP method permission. In the end, I documented the process and sent it to each of our companies so it could be implemented as I never found a better way.

Comment: Do you know HOW it does this?

Comment: No; I don't know the inner workings of any AV. However, I would suspect that the program can tell who the current user is (I don't meant logged in user - I mean local or an RDP) and block it. This behaviour is (IMO) desirable as it means if someone got on your machine without your permission then the default is to remain on!

Comment: Local users can access the interface, RDP users can, Synergy keyboard/mouse cannot, havent tried with VNC for a while but i suspect it works. The thing is WHY can't synergy interact with KIS and HOW does KIS manage to stop such interaction?